# Добавить id по name и установить selected

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

```
<select name="type_account">
  <option label="" value=""></option>
  <option label="букет 1" value="4">букет 1</option>
  <option label="букет 2" value="2">букет 2</option>
  <option label="букет 3" value="1" selected="selected">букет 3</option>
  <option label="букет 4" value="3">букет 4</option>
</select>
```

Собственно нужно добавить `select`'у c `name="type_account"` `id=buket`, а затем по этому `id` задать `option` по умолчанию `букет 3` (`selected`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем ясень вопрос, если Вы хотите по этому ID управлять значением элемента select, тогда это можно сделать так:

```
document.querySelector('select[name="type_account"]').id = "buket";
document.getElementById("buket").value = 1; // букет 3
```